# how to make pandas dataframe Fortran type ordered

Tags: python, performance, pandas, numpy

I knew a little that inside python pandas package, the dataframe has part that was constructed with NumPy NDArrays. And numpy has the option that you can choose your data order type, like 'C' or 'F'.

Since I always have to implement lots of ops on columns on huge dataframe(like 100 million lines), I expected If I have the chance to transfer dataframe from c type to f type, I could enhance the performance a lot, right?

if so, how could I do that? or simply using numpy, as pandas dataframe is not a must, a quick answer is actually.

Thanks

Comment: I don't believe this at all possible with pandas, sorry.

Comment: Unlike `numpy` that operates in terms of _arrays_ and _dimensions_, `pandas` uses _tables_ with _rows_ and _columns_. This approach is intrinsically asymmetric.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Interestingly, Pandas uses internally C order numpy array for each column. Whenever you access multiple columns or all of dataframe, it joins those numpy arrays and returns a Fortran order numpy array.

```
print(df[df.columns[0]].values.flags)
print(df[df.columns[0:2]].values.flags)
print(df.values.flags)

#Single column
C_CONTIGUOUS : True
F_CONTIGUOUS : True

#Multiple columns
C_CONTIGUOUS : False
F_CONTIGUOUS : True

#Entire dataframe
C_CONTIGUOUS : False
F_CONTIGUOUS : True
```

So, column operations are very fast (add/edit/delete etc). That's why iterating over rows is slow in dataframe. 
If your program has more row operations, convert it to C order as below.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.ascontiguousarray(df.values), columns=df.columns)
```

Whenever I am done with processing in columns, I convert it to C contiguous array because scaling, batch training DNN is much faster in C order array.

Comment: I like this answer, however one thing is not clear to me.  If we are talking about a single column of a dataframe, does it make sense to talk about order at all?  If an array is 1-d there is only one possible order, i.e. C order and F order will always be the same in this setting.

Comment: That's right. for 1 column, both C order and F order are contiguous. First line in above code shows that. so, no issues for single column. For multiple columns only, it makes sense to convert to C order contiguous to speedup scaling and DNN training.